# Moving a file from a to b

Tags: java, file, installation

This is my actual moving code:

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class CopyFileMac {

        public void COPY(){
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            Component aComponent = null;
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);

             if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                 } 
            else 
            {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Selected Cancel");
                 System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Demo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class FileMover {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        CopyFilePc CopyFilePc = new CopyFilePc();
        CopyFileMac CopyFileMac = new CopyFileMac();
        String MacOrPc;

        MacOrPc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you have a Mac or PC?");

        if (MacOrPc.equalsIgnoreCase("mac"))
         {
            CopyFileMac.COPY();
        }

        if (MacOrPc.equals("pc"))
        {
            CopyFilePc.COPY();
        }
```

I want to move ~/Downloads/FILE

To ~/Application support \ minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar (the .jar will be unzipped into a folder)

Comment: I don't see a question in your question.

Comment: I want to move the files and i dont know how to define a path and move one file to another location

Comment: If that's your question, it would be useful to mention it in your post. Nobody is going to give you full working code (unless they really have a lot of free time); you have to point us at what you're stuck at, so that we can help you with that.

Comment: *"Do you have a Mac or PC?"*  What to do if the answer is 'no' or 'ubuntu' or..

Answer (score 0):

First solution at google on "java move an file": [how to move/copy a file in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/)
Hope this helps :)